# Deploying Laravel 5.2 on Apache server (Directory issues)

Tags: php, apache, laravel, server, hosting

So, I am new to Laravel and I have never hosted an application on shared server. I have followed some tutorials but I have some confusions. I have two Laravel projects, one is called **Laravel** and the other **Project**. Both are placed in `/var/www/html`

In Laravel/public/index.php, I have

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

and this works when I run it in my browser as `(ip-address)/laravel/public`.
But when I run Project with the same configuration, it doesn't work.

I am sure, there is something I am doing wrong but I can't understand what. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: do you have setup vhosts for both?

Comment: do you have added follow symlinks in .htaccess?

Comment: please tell us the error you are retrieving while requesting Project

Comment: where is your configuration? did you add your projects to hosts?

Comment: @aimme, No that is not added.

Comment: @akhilp2255 when I access it through the browser, it says:
The page isn't working.
(ip-address) is currently unable to handle the request.